# Easy way to place map markers at targets from UAV darter turret view?

Tags: arma-3

When I am controlling the turret of an auto-hovering UAV darter, and I spot an enemy player from the view of the turret, how can I then *easily* mark that enemy player on the **map** so my teammates can see the location on the map and set a waypoint to it? (Not talking about laser-designating. This would be so that infantry units can move to the enemy location)

The way I have been doing this so far, is to switch to map view, try to guess where the enemy player is, and place a waypoint at that guessed location. Then, switch back to UAV turret view and see how far away my waypoint is from the target's actual location. This winds up taking at least several (and usually many more) attempts at walking the waypoint onto the target. Sometimes this can take almost a minute to get an exact marker on the map for teammates to see.

Does anyone have better solution??

Note: I am usually not the squad leader, so I wouldn't have the squad commands (F keys) at my disposal to mark locations from within the turret view.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the standard uav that come with arma 3. The uav mod "RQ-11B RAVEN" does allow for a click in turret view to be translated into a marker on the map.